# Set proxy on app

Tags: java, android, proxy, firebase

I'm trying to connect to my Firebase backend, however, due to the proxy server on my campus, I'm unable to do so. Is there a workaround for this? The app is able to connect on 3G or my home network, but fails on campus.

I'm trying to use the following code to set proxy but it's not working.

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "10.2.20.17");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
```

Comment: You can edit here too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27546757/gcm-push-notifications-not-coming-through-proxy/27622388?noredirect=1#comment43689674_27622388

Comment: neways hopefully you are connecting to https server, use https.proxyHost instead of http.proxyHost

Comment: Yeah, it's not working either. HTTP or HTTPS. Neither are working.

Comment: whart error reponse you are getting???

Comment: There is no error response. It just fails to connect.

Comment: are you sure there is not a port firewall in your campus? maybe they do not forward requests to 8080 ports. It is common that they allow 80,443 and some other (SMTP etc), but block other ports

Comment: Is there a way to find it out?

Comment: maybe use another proxy (if you don't have one, get some from hidemyass.com with 80 or 443 port) and check an http url to see if working

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect from other locations, it is definitely a firewall issue. Port 8080 may be blocked in your campus; if possible, use a proxy with port 80, 443 (these are usually open).

If you cannot find a direct proxy with 80 or 443 (https) to your backend, then use a custom mediator proxy with 80, 443 that connects to your desired 8080 proxy :)

Comment: I'm a bit new to this, could you please elaborate what do mean by "port 8080 may be blocked" when this is how we set the proxy: http://i.stack.imgur.com/sxSmP.jpg

How would I go about obtaining a mediator proxy?

Comment: Need a clarification on this. I understand that you are you able to connect with your code when you are outside from your campus, but not when you are in your campus? am I right?

Comment: What about the browser? is it able to connect (inside your campus) with your 8080 proxy?

Comment: Yeah, the browser is able to connect as well as some apps like Snapchat while some (WhatsApp, Instagram) cannot.

Comment: so, maybe they block certain domains/IPs (Snapchat is not in their list, while the others are). Which domain are you trying to connect to, can you access this domain from your browser?

Comment: Firebase connections are made using a custom URL like "https://<your-app-name>.firebaseio.com". It's highly unlikely that they block that. I'm able to open that URL in my browser, however, it fails to connect using Android SDK.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67611/discussion-between-konstantinos-chalkias-and-rafay).