# Push Notification with proxy

Tags: android, proxy, notifications

I'm stuck with a strange android behavior and I'd appreciate if anyone can suggest me how to proceed.

I’v developed an App with gcm first, now upgraded to fcm, to just send messages and notifications from a server. Everything goes well using this app with mobile connectivity or with wifi on an open network, but the devices stop to receive notifications when they are connected to a wifi behind a proxy.

The proxy is of course configured on the device and they can surf on internet, read email, connect to the machine with the gcm server installed; they just don’t receive notification… and not only for my app but for all apps, like hangouts, whatsapp and gmail…

Probably google play service cannot connect with google server… but what can I do to force it?

I can manage all the network settings, I've removed the firewall, all ports are open. If I connect to the normal gateway everything works, if I connect devices to this transparent proxy, notifications stop to arrive.

I’v read on forums that most users use “Drony” or they root the smartphones, unfortunately these devices are in a production environment and under warranty, I cannot install third-party app or root the devices.

In my app I don’t manage directly proxy configuration, this is a OS configuration, but is it normal that android notifications don’t work behind a proxy?

**Update:**
       following this topic  https://stackoverflow.com/a/31832657/2358012
       and dialing `*#*#426#*#*`
       it gives me that using proxy, google play services are disconnected ->             connection failed.
       Probably the TCP connection doesn't pass through the proxy.
       I've set up also a SOCKS server, but in Android, without root, is not possible to configure SOCKS connection, right?

Comment: You are absolutely awesome! I happened to be a network/system admin, troubleshooting Slack app connection issues. They pointed me in your direction.

The port 5228 is closed on your network firewall, and that is the port Google uses for play push.

If you also happened to be using a proxy that decrypts SSL/HTTPs, you must also allow the port in proxy config *plus* allow SSL Tunnel to ^http(s)://.*mtalk.google.com/.*$

Answer (score 0):

all depends on your Company campus network access policy. You can not do if your

company campus proxy firewall doesn't provide access to these sites. However, you

can ask them to allow these URL through their proxy firewall.

use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27546757/gcm-push-notifications-not-coming-through-proxy) for ur refrence it is ok then please vote here